# working with objects in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

So I am fairly new to asp.net MVC. When someone requests a list of items from the database, the controller gets the items and sends them to the view with

```
View(items);
```

the view knows what they are via:

```
@model IEnumerable<SomeType>
```

and then the list is displayed via:

```
foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr><td>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.id })<td>@item.id</td><td>@item.name</td></tr>
}
```

but lets say I want to click on edit (which I guess triggers some controller, I haven't even implemented the edit page yet), how can I pass that object that was used to fill that particular row to the edit controller? Or do I have to get the object again via a lookup of its id into the database? Or do I just fill all of that new { } with my variables and they get passed in that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you will need to query that object again with it's Id parameter.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id) 
{
    var entity = db.Query(id);
    return View(entity);
}
```

Remember that [HTTP is stateless](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol). This means that the first request (to list the items) has no relation with the second request (to view the edit form of a given item).

Answer (score 0):

You just get the ID of entity to be edited in your controller action method and inside that edit method you have to fetch the object from database and present it to user on edit view for editing.